# I want to create active directory groups for all domain joined servers via group policy.Is that possible?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I want to create active directory groups via group policy for every server I join to the domain so that I don't need to create groups manually. Is that possible ?

Comment: No, but you can create a scheduled task that checks for new servers and creates the group accordingly.

Comment: Hey @GregAskew...can you please help me out on this one ?

Comment: Maybe you need to attempt to figure out a solution first. For example, you could create a Powershell script that does an LDAP query for new computer objects with a server OS in Active Directory and creates the group. Scheduled to run every day or whatever interval suits. Hint: after the first (manual) run, the query might specify server computers with a `WhenCreated` date greater than the last time the script ran, otherwise it'll try creating the same groups over and over.